# what is the "get" button on the apple tv 4?

Tags: appletv

According to [Using Netflix on your Apple TV](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/23887), "*in the App Store, search for Netflix to find our app, then choose Get to start installation.*"

Where is the "Get" button? There is no option on the App Store screen:

[image]

It's not on the remote either: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205305

Any ideas?

Comment: You already have Netflix installed.  The "Get" button would be contained within the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the listing of the Netflix app in the App Store.

Click on the Netflix app (press the touch surface till it clicks) you have highlighted in your screen shot. This will take you to the app page for the Netflix app and there will be a get button on that page. Click on "Get".

Comment: When I click on the icon it gets slightly bigger momentarily and then returns to its original size and that's it. I could make a video of what the icon does but can't really present any evidence that I'm pressing the button (I am). I mean, even if I got the remote in the video with my hand on it there wouldn't be any way for you to know that I was applying sufficient pressure to the button...

Comment: @neubert Then you might not be clicking correctly, or you remote might be faulty. Still, you managed to get into the App Store, so... Are you sure you're actually pressing the touch surface down to get a click? It might also be that you're accidentally moving your finger slightly on the touch surface so the click doesn't register.

Comment: So I don't think it was actually installed. Apparently I couldn't install any apps from the app store unless I had a credit card associated with my iTunes account. Really stupid stuff imho. I shouldn't need a credit card to install a free app. Meh.